# pdf of the product of two independent uniform random variables $X,Y \sim U(-1,1)$

Tags: probability, distributions

Using the product distribution. I have $Z = XY$ with $X,Y \sim U(-1,1)$ and independent. Thus
\begin{align}
f_Z(z) & = \frac{1}{4} \int_{-1}^1 I_{[-1 < \frac{z}{x} < 1]} \ \frac{dx}{|x|} \\
& = \frac{1}{4} \left[ \int_0^1 I_{[-x < z < x]} \ \frac{dx}{x} + \int_{-1}^0 I_{[-x > z > x]} \ \frac{dx}{-x} \right].
\end{align}
I am not sure what to do to finish since it seems I will end up with an $\ln z$ with $z < 0$...

Comment: This indicator function is either 0 or 1. You can eliminate by writing $$\int_{-1}^1 I_{[-1 < \frac{z}{x} < 1]} \ \frac{dx}{|x|} = \int_{\text{interval for $x$ where $|z/x|<1$}}  \frac{1}{|x|} dx $$ drawing a plot of $x$ and $y$ might help you.

Comment: I have done this, but I keep getting an undefined result when $x < 0$. Can you expand?

Comment: I have done this exercise when $X,Y$ are standard uniform, but have found this to be trickier for whatever reason.

Comment: For "$\text{interval for $x$ where $|z/x|<1$}$" you get $x>|z|$ and $x<-|z|$. This second case is not undefined because you have in the expression $\frac{1}{|x|}$ the *absolute* value of $x$.

\begin{align}
f_Z(z) & = \frac{1}{4} \int_{-1}^1 I_{[-1 < \frac{z}{x} < 1]} \ \frac{dx}{|x|} \\
& = \frac{1}{4} \left[ \int_{|z|}^1 \frac{dx}{x} + \int_{-1}^{-|z|}  \frac{dx}{-x} \right]\\
& = \frac{2}{4} \int_{|z|}^1 \frac{dx}{x} \\ &= -0.5 \log(|z|)
\end{align}

Comment: an alternative route would be to work with for the positive values $X>0$ and $Y>0$ with the transformed varialbe $$U = -\log(Z) = -\log(X) -\log(Y)$$ and these $-log(X)$ are exponential distributed and their sum is Erlang distributed. Then $$F_{U|X>0,Y>0}(u) = 1- e^{-u} - u e^{-u}$$ and substituting $-u = \log(z)$ (and inversion of sign, because $P(Z \leq z) = P(U \geq -log(z))$ you get to $$F_{Z|X>0,Y>0}(z) = 1-1 +z - \log(z)z = z - \log(z)z $$ with derivative $$f_{Z|X>0,Y>0}(z) =  -\log(z) $$